# Why does Express Multer require the input field name be the same as the string that's passed to the middleware?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware, multer

From the [documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/multer.html):
**Fronend**

```
<form action="/profile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="avatar" />
</form>
```

**Backend:**

```
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })
 app.post('/profile', upload.single('avatar'), function (req, res, next) {
      // req.file is the `avatar` file
      // req.body will hold the text fields, if there were any
    })
```

I have successfully implemented file upload with Multer previously. But, now I am facing a problem, where I am sending an object containing some information, along with the file, **not just the file**. So I have been struggling to understand how this:

```
upload.single('avatar')
```

works. And there seems to be no explanation online aside from the fact that the string passed must be the same as the field input name which, if anything, made the whole thing more confusing.

Comment: That string `'avatar'`is how multer knows which item in the form you are asking it to parse.  Remember, `upload.single()` targets a single field in the form data so somehow you have to tell multer which field you are targeting.  This name is how you do that.

Comment: Express [HTTP-method functions](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.METHOD) like `app.post` can take multiple `(req, res)` middleware functions that are processed in sequence. The invocation `upload.single(...)` generates such a `(req,res)` middleware function, which operates on the specified field name. This means that the function object returned by `upload.single('avatar')` runs first, then your subsequent function expression runs next.

Comment: If I send the formData inside an object (with the additional information that I need in the backend), this doesn't work. And I didn't find a way to make multer to target the formData inside the object;

Comment: Possibly you could add an additional middleware function prior to `upload.single('avatar')` to populate `req` to look how Multer expects. There might be a way to configure Multer to look in the right place, though, instead of changing what you supply to Multer. You've shown what does work, so could you show what your modified non-working approach looks like, too? Or is this your non-working approach

Comment: @apsillers to be honest, I didn't change a thing even though I knew it wouldn't work. However, I just had no idea what to do to make multer get the formData from the object inside req.body.

Comment: `upload.single()` reads raw form data at the top level of the POST, not form data embedded inside your own object.  It would have no idea how to find that or where in the request to look for it.  As it stands now this an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem#:~:text=What%20is%20it%3F,trouble%2C%20you%20ask%20about%20Y.) where you are failing to describe the actual top level problem you're trying to solve and instead are muddying around in details of attempted solutions to some problem you don't tell us about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you have a form with 3 fields:

- Name (text)
- email (text)
- Photo (file)

When sending this form in json format, Nodejs will receive data like bellow:

```
"{"name": "value", "email": "value", "photo": "[binary]"}"
```

So far so good. Here multer can know easily that the field to parse is "photo".

Now imagine for some reasons, your backend ask you to parse all input value to binary before sending the form. Now you have to convert your input form and send it as below:

```
"{"name": "[binary]", "email": "[binary]", "photo": "[binary]"}"
```

Multer: "Okay, I have 3 binary fields, which one should I convert to file ?"